# sympy solver runs out of memory when using symbol in exp()

Tags: python, sympy

I am attempting to learn how to use sympy, so I've picked off a simple problem to attempt. when I attempt to use Sympy's solver to solve `e^(-(ln(2)/8) * t) - 10^-6` eventually my repl crashes with an out of memory error. It seem to be something with how it interprets the exp() method that I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

```py
from math import log as ln
from sympy import exp as e, symbols as sym, solve

t = sym('t')
hl = 8.0197
k = ln(2)/hl #lambda 
expression = e(-k * t) -10**-6

# 10^6 = e^(-k * t)
days = solve(,t)
print(days)
```

It should solve to ~159.5, but as noted it causes the repl to crash. with `“ipython3” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`10**-6` is a suspiciously small number.

Since floating-point numbers are [scary](http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html), we can solve a similar problem to the one you pose using nice, safe integers:

```
from math import log as ln
import sympy
from sympy import symbols as sym

t  = sym('t')
hl = 8.0197
k  = 4
expression = sympy.exp(-k * t) - 3

days = sympy.solve(expression,t)
print(days)
```

This instantly returns:

```
[log(3**(3/4)/3) + I*pi, log(3**(3/4)/3), log(-3**(3/4)*I/3), log(3**(3/4)*I/3)]
```

So we know right away that the problem has something to do with the use of floating-point numbers. As it turns out, this is a [known problem](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/2648) in SymPy. Note that since there are four possible solutions to the equation, however much work it takes to handle the floating-point numbers is quadrupled.

Since working with floating-point numbers can result in [lost precision](http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html), especially if the dynamic range of the numbers is large, SymPy converts floating-point inputs into exact fractional representations. This can result in really big numbers that slow calculations down.

The solution is to avoid floating-point numbers when possible and, more generally, to solve the equation symbolically and substitute afterwards:

```
from math import log as ln
import sympy
from sympy import symbols as sym

t = sym('t')
k = sym('k')
c = sym('c')
expression = sympy.exp(-k * t) - c

days = sympy.solve(expression,t)
print(days)
```

This gives:

```
[log(1/c)/k]
```

Which can be evaluated using

```
hl   = 8.0197
kval = ln(2)/hl #lambda 
days[0].subs([(k,kval), (c, 10**-6)])
```

which gives

```
159.845200455409
```

Comment: what does it mean to be "suspiciously small?"

Comment: @alec_a: Values such as `10^-6` often show up in code as fudges for or safeguards against floating-point issues. Even when they're used outside such contexts, they can cause problems. In this case, there are six orders of magnitude between two of the constants. Since the code seemed otherwise reasonable, the high dynamic range caused me to suspect a floating-point issue.